# case class from Map

Tags: scala, maps, case-class

I'm trying to implement (de)serialization from Scala case classes to Maps (field_name -> field_value). The problem is I don't know how to create a function, that would take a case class type and a map, instantiate, populate and return it. I've seen this done in some JSON libraries, but I don't get the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this for a particular case class is trivial:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Foo(x: Int, y: Double, z: String) {
  def toMap = Map('x -> x, 'y -> y, 'z -> z)
}
object Foo {
  def apply(vals: Map[Symbol, Any]): Foo = Foo(vals('x).asInstanceOf[Int], vals('y).asInstanceOf[Double], vals('z).asInstanceOf[String])
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined module Foo

scala> Foo(Map('x -> 1, 'y -> 2.0, 'z -> "wibble"))
res0: Foo = Foo(1,2.0,wibble)

scala> res0.toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Any] = Map('x -> 1, 'y -> 2.0, 'z -> wibble)
```

But I'm guessing that you want to create something that works for any case class, where you don't necessarily know what the names of the values are?

In which case, you're going to have to take a look at reflection (added in Scala 2.10.0):

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

You can use reflection to iterate over the members of a class, find out what their names are and then create your map. For example:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[Foo].members filter { m => m.isMethod && m.asMethod.isStable }
res2: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(value z, value y, value x)
```

Comment: What about the other direction, `Map(fieldName -> fieldValue)` to case class?

Comment: You want to create a new case class which has members with the names of the keys of the map? In that case you'll need type macros, which are in development right now: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/typemacros.html

Comment: (unless of course, you know what the keys in the map are ahead of time, and already have a case class with the right members - in which case simple reflection will suffice)

Comment: Right, I think in the original question the use-case was when you know the type of the case class and have a `Map` with the correct `(fieldName -> fieldValue)` pairs. I think this could also be solved in a type-safe manner with macros, and may actually be more elegant and performant than reflection.

Comment: Ah - I was guessing that that wasn't what the OP was interested in. I've updated the example to show deserialization in the trivial case.

Comment: And you're right - a normal (def) macro could be used to remove some of this boilerplate.

Comment: No I think he meant a function like `deserialize[T](map: Map[String, Any]): T` where `T` is a case class, or some other way of providing the type information. (At least something along those lines is what I would be interested in)

Comment: Perhaps we should allow the OP to clarify what he's actually asking :-) Your example could certainly be implemented as a def macro.

Comment: Yes, I need what dicarlo2 said, but with [String, String], as I will be using Redis.

Comment: Right - a def macro is definitely what you're after. The "bones" of the solution will be the same as the reflection example in my answer (macros are built on top of reflection - but at compile time instead of runtime). I'm afraid that I don't have time to knock together an example (it won't be trivial - you'll have to construct trees within your macro). The new quasiquoting functionality in development in 2.11 will make this kind of thing much easier, but that's not available outside of a 2.11 pre-release.